replaces "which"?
Which word replaces "which" in "one of which" in this sentence? ( clause or sentences )
Complex sentences are sentences which have more than one clause, at least one of which will be a
main clause

Edit
The antecedent of the relative pronoun which is the noun phrase more than one clause, and hence the sentence means

Complex sentences are sentences which have more than one clause; at least one of these clauses will be a main clause.


One could say that the antecedent is the noun phrase "more than one clause".

Thanks, @BillJ.  I have edited my answer.
